# How to fill an item in the viewmodel of type list and return it to view without erasing the other fields of a form .NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm trying to fill a string list in my viewmodel by the view, and then return to the same with the other fields the way the user has filled them, and that without having to pass all my model to the controler, Sending only my list.

My OS View Model

```
   public class OsViewModel
    {


        [Key]
        public int OSId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Código")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o código da OS")]
        public string CodigoOS { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o descrição da OS")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Natureza OS")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione uma opção")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a natureza da OS")]
        public string Natureza { get; set; }

        public int codigoNatureza { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Req")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o código de requisição da OS")]
        public string CodigoReq { get; set; }

        public DateTime? SLA { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Prev. Ínicio")]
        public DateTime? ProgInic { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Prev. Fim")]
        public DateTime? ProgFim { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ínicio Real")]
        public DateTime? RealInic { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fim Real")]
        public DateTime? RealFim { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Dt Lançamento")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a data de lançamento da OS.")]
        public DateTime? DtLancamento { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Dt Status")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a data em que a OS foi cadastrada.")]
        public DateTime? DtStatus { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Horas Prev.")]
        public string QtdHorasPrev { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Horas Reais")]
        public string QtdHorasRealizadas { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "VL. Mat")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o valor Material da OS")]
        public decimal? ValorMaterial { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "VL. Serv")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o valor de Serviço da OS")]
        public decimal? ValorServico { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "VL. Tot")]
        public decimal? ValorTotal { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tot. Pen")]
        public decimal? ValoeDependenciaFaturado { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "M. Faturado ?")]
        public bool ValorMaterialFaturado { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "S. Faturado ?")]
        public bool ValorServicoFaturado { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "VL. Tot Fat.")]
        public decimal? ValorTotalFaturado { get; set; }

        public int codigoStatus { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status OS")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione uma opção")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o Status da OS")]
        public EnumStatusOS StatusDaOS { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Técnicos")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A OS deve possuir pelo menos um Técnico.")]
        public int[] chkTecnicos { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SelectListItem> listaTecnicos { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SelectListItem> StatusOS { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SelectListItem> NaturezaOS { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TecnicoViewModel> Tecnicos { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<InfoOsViewModel> Status { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ObservacoesOSViewModel> ObservacoesOS { get; set; }

        public virtual List<string> Observacoes { get; set; }

    }
```

The list what i want to pass to my controller is :

```
 public virtual List<string> Observacoes { get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IncluirObservacoes(IEnumerable<InclusoesOsViewModel> inclusoes)
{

    OsViewModel os = new OsViewModel {
        //get inclusoes items
    };


    //TempData["Message"] = new[] { Resources.altera_sucesso, "sucesso" };
    return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "O cadastro foi realizado com sucesso" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My view model who receive my ajax request items:

```
 public class InclusoesOsViewModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

        public int value { get; set; }

        public DateTime data { get; set; }

        public List<string> observacoes { get; set; }
    }
```

And, my view:

```
@model ControleOS.Apresentacao.MVC.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.OS.OsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cadastrar";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class="row m-0 form-group fg-float">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("IncluirObservacoes", "Os", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmCadastrarOS" }))
            {

                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" style="float: right; text-transform: uppercase;">Salvar</button>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Gerenciar", "OS")" class="btn btn-warning waves-effect espaco" style="float: right; text-transform: uppercase;">Retornar</a>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@Model.Observacoes


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var listaTecnicos = [];
        var listaObservacoes = [];

        //$("#Salvar").click(function () {
        //    localStorage.removeItem("menus");
        //});

        $("#btn-modalTecnicos").click(function () {
            $("#listaDeTecnicos").empty();
            $("#modal_tecnicos").modal("show");
        });

        $("#btn-retornarTecnicos").click(function () {
            $("#modal_tecnicos").modal("hide");
        });

        $("#btn-salvarTecnicos").click(function () {
            $("#modal_tecnicos").modal("hide");
            $.each(listaTecnicos, function (i) {
                $("#listaDeTecnicos").append('<li data-filtertext="' + listaTecnicos[i] + '">' + listaTecnicos[i] + '</li>');

            });
        });


        $(".checkTecnicos").click(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                var tecnico = $(this).attr("data-valuetwo");
                listaTecnicos.push(tecnico);
            }
            else {
                var tecnico = $(this).attr("data-valuetwo");
                listaTecnicos.pop(tecnico);
            }
        });

        //Observacao

        $("#btn-modalObservacoes").click(function () {
            $("#listaDeObservacoes").empty();
            $("#modal_observacoes").modal("show");
        });

        $("#btn-retornarObservacoes").click(function () {
            $("#modal_observacoes").modal("hide");
        });

        $("#btn-salvarObservacoes").click(function () {
            $("#modal_observacoes").modal("hide");
            var observacao = $("#txt-incluirObservacao").val();
            incluirObservacao(observacao);
        });



        function incluirObservacao(observacao) {
            listaObservacoes.push(observacao);
            $.each(listaObservacoes, function (i) {
                $("#listaDeObservacoes").append('<li data-filtertext="' + listaObservacoes[i] + '">' + listaObservacoes[i] + '</li>');
            });
            @*@Model.Observacoes = @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaObservacoes);*@
        };

        $("#frmCadastrarOS").submit(function (e) {

            var postData = $("#frmCadastrarOS").serializeArray();
            var model = @Html.Raw(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("IncluirObservacoes", "OS")",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("sucesso");
                    $("#modal_observacoes").modal("hide");
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log("erro");
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    })
</script>
```

My partial view model, Who is responsible for sending the itens in my modals.

```
@model ControleOS.Apresentacao.MVC.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.OS.OsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_CreateOrEdit";
    //13890
}

<style>
    .fg-float .fg-label {
        color:#6B1F7C !important;
    }
</style>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <fieldset class="col-md-12">
            <legend>ORDEM DE SERVIÇO</legend>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group fg-float col-md-1">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CodigoOS, new { @class = "form-control fg-input negrito", @maxlength = "6" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CodigoOS, new { @class = "fg-label", @id = "text-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CodigoOS, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group fg-float col-md-1">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CodigoReq, new { @class = "form-control fg-input negrito", @maxlength = "6" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CodigoReq, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CodigoReq, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="select">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.codigoStatus, Model.StatusOS.Select(option => new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = option.Text,
                       Value = option.Value,
                       Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Value == Model.codigoStatus.ToString())
                   }), "Selecione o Satatus da OS", new { @id = "ddlStatusDaOS", @SortDirection = "ASC", @sort = "true", @class = "form-control roxo negrito" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.codigoStatus, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="select">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.codigoNatureza, Model.NaturezaOS.Select(option => new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = option.Text,
                       Value = option.Value,
                       Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Value == Model.codigoNatureza.ToString())
                   }), "Selecione a Natureza da OS", new { @id = "ddlNaturezaDaOS", @SortDirection = "ASC", @sort = "true", @class = "form-control roxo negrito" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.codigoNatureza, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DtLancamento, new { @class = "form-control fg-input date negrito" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DtLancamento, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DtLancamento, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger negrito" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DtStatus, new { @class = "form-control fg-input date negrito" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DtStatus, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DtStatus, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SLA, new { @class = "form-control fg-input date negrito", @id = "destaqueSLA" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SLA, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SLA, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row m-t-10">
                <div class="form-group fg-float col-md-12">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control fg-input negrito" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Descricao, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descricao, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger " })
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <fieldset class="col-md-12 m-t-20">
            <legend>OBSERVAÇÕES</legend>
            <div class="pmb-block">
                <div class="pmbb-header">
                    <h4>
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-collection-text m-r-5"></i>Observações
                        <a href="#" id="btn-modalObservacoes" class="btn btn-success waves-effect espaco pull-right auto-size" style="float: right; margin-top:-10px; padding:6px,2px,6px,2px;"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="pmbb-body p-l-30">
                    <div class="pmbb-view">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="listaDeObservacoes"></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <fieldset class="col-md-6 m-t-20">
            <legend>PROGRAMAÇÃO</legend>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProgInic, new { @class = "form-control fg-input date" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProgInic, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProgInic, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProgFim, new { @class = "form-control fg-input date" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProgFim, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProgFim, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QtdHorasPrev, new { @class = "form-control fg-input" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QtdHorasPrev, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QtdHorasPrev, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="col-md-6 m-t-20">
            <legend>REALIZAÇÃO</legend>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RealInic, new { @class = "form-control fg-input date" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RealInic, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RealInic, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RealFim, new { @class = "form-control fg-input date" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RealFim, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RealFim, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QtdHorasRealizadas, new { @class = "form-control fg-input" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QtdHorasRealizadas, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QtdHorasRealizadas, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <fieldset class="col-md-12 m-t-20">
            <legend>TÉCNICOS</legend>
            <div class="pmb-block">
                <div class="pmbb-header">
                    <h4>
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-wrench m-r-5"></i>Técnicos
                        <a href="#" id="btn-modalTecnicos" class="btn btn-success waves-effect espaco pull-right" style="float: right; margin-top:-10px; padding:6px,2px,6px,2px;"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="pmbb-body p-l-30">
                    <div class="pmbb-view">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="listaDeTecnicos"></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <fieldset class="col-md-12 m-t-20 m-b-20">
            <legend>ORÇAMENTO</legend>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValorMaterial, new { @class = "form-control fg-input money2" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ValorMaterial, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValorMaterial, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1 form-group fg-float" style="margin-left:3%;">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValorServico, new { @class = "form-control fg-input money2" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ValorServico, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValorServico, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 form-group fg-float">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ValorServicoFaturado, new SelectList(
                new[]
                 {
                    new { Value = "true", Text = "Serviço faturado" },
                    new { Value = "false", Text = "Serviço não faturado" },
                },
                "Value",
                "Text",
                Model
                 ), new { @id = "", @SortDirection = "ASC", @sort = "true", @class = "form-control roxo" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValorServicoFaturado, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 form-group fg-float">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ValorMaterialFaturado, new SelectList(
                new[]
                 {
                    new { Value = "true", Text = "Material faturado" },
                    new { Value = "false", Text = "Material não faturado" },
                },
                "Value",
                "Text",
                Model
                 ), new { @id = "", @SortDirection = "ASC", @sort = "true", @class = "form-control roxo" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValorMaterialFaturado, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValorTotalFaturado, new { @class = "form-control fg-input money2" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ValorTotalFaturado, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValorTotalFaturado, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1 form-group fg-float" style="margin-left:2%;">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValoeDependenciaFaturado, new { @class = "form-control fg-input money2" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ValoeDependenciaFaturado, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValoeDependenciaFaturado, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1 form-group fg-float">
                    <div class="fg-line">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValorTotal, new { @class = "form-control fg-input money2" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ValorTotal, new { @class = "fg-label" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValorTotal, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal_tecnicos" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" align="center">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:auto;">
            <div class="modal-header" align="center" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="zmdi zmdi-wrench m-r-5"></i> Selecione os técnicos abaixo</h4>
                <hr style="margin-top:10px;" />
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" align="center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12 m-b-15 z-depth-1">
                        <h4 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #673673;">Técnicos</h4>
                        @foreach (var tecnicos in Model.listaTecnicos)
                        {
                            <div class="col-md-6 checkbox" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align:center;">
                                <label id="chk-Tecnicos" class="pull-left">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkTecnicos" data-valuetwo="@tecnicos.Text" style="margin-left:-20px;" name="chkTecnicos" checked="@tecnicos.Selected" value="@tecnicos.Value">
                                    <i class="input-helper" id="chkicon"></i>
                                    @tecnicos.Text
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.chkTecnicos, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" type="button" id="btn-retornarTecnicos" class="btn btn-warning">Retornar</a>
                <a href="#" type="button" id="btn-salvarTecnicos" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal_observacoes" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" align="center">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:auto;">
            <div class="modal-header" align="center" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="zmdi zmdi-collection-text m-r-5"></i>Incluir nova observação</h4>
                <hr style="margin-top:10px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" align="center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12 m-b-15 z-depth-1">
                        <h4 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #673673;">Observações</h4>                        
                        <div class="row m-t-10 m-t-20">
                            <div class="form-group fg-float col-md-12">
                                <div class="fg-line">
                                    <div class="fg-line">
                                        <input type="text" id="txt-incluirObservacao" class="form-control">
                                        <label class="fg-label">Observação</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descricao, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger " })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.Observacoes, "", new { @class = "has-error text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" type="button" id="btn-retornarObservacoes" class="btn btn-warning">Retornar</a>
                <a href="#" type="button" id="btn-salvarObservacoes" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how can I send to my controller as the user inserts into my list and return it filled in my view so that I can then send my OsViewModel in the form normally?

Basic, I want to pass my listaObservacoes[] to my @Model.Observacoes.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please revise and be clear about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to fill in my list without leaving the registration page. And besides, I can not erase the other fields, if the user already has them filled out.

Comment: What issue are you having exactly? Simply, whatever endpoint you hit via your AJAX call, should return the HTML/data you need. Then, you just utilize JavaScript to manipulate the DOM accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for a way where I can fill my list that is in the view model from that return, is there any way?

Comment: I think you're missing the concept of client-server here. Your view model, etc. is only a thing server-side. Once you're client-side, all you have is a DOM based on the HTML response from the server. There is no view model to update. Just change the appropriate HTML directly via JavaScript.

Comment: I know that. But good, I've never done this kind of service before, so I'll still be accepting suggestions, but then I'll use ajax to return my viewmodel with the filled list and try to adapt it in html. Thx, Chris.

Comment: When I get a new template in my ajax request. How can I associate it with my @ HTML.TextBorFor (d => d.Observations)? I already use JSON.Parse(Data) to get a new object.

Comment: Again, all you have is HTML, so based on the `TextBoxFor` call, you'd have an input element with an id of `#Observations` most likely. You can then use JavaScript to select that element from the DOM (e.g. `document.getElementById('Observations')`) and change it's `value` attribute, `innerHTML`, etc., depending on what you're trying to achieve (which still isn't clear).

Answer (score 0):

The list of listaObservacoes values must be sent in the form, so the form must include tags like "input" with the same name as you have as a list of string in your model: "Observacoes" and listaObservacoes  values should be in the tags.
you can create these tags dynamically using jquery before form is submitted.

in your form, you need a place for your dynamic tags with an id like "dynamic-tags":

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("IncluirObservacoes", "Os", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmCadastrarOS" }))
        {

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)

            <div id="dynamic-tags"></div>

            <div class="col-md-12" ... // the rest of the form
               
        }
```

and before form is sumbitted, you need to create dynamic tags like so:

```
 $("#frmCadastrarOS").submit(function (e) {
 
 $.each(listaObservacoes, function(i,v){
 $("#dynamic-tags").append(`<intput type="text"   name="Observacoes[${i}]" value="${v}"  />`)
})
```